# Can you sneak attack with a move action with the spell Defenestrating Sphere?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, actions, sneak-attack

The spell Defenestrating Sphere (Sor/Wiz 4) has a duration of 1 rd./level. The spell description reads:

> When you cast this spell, you create a violently swirling sphere of
>   air. As a move action, you can make the sphere travel up to 30 feet
>   per round and strike a creature or object you **indicate as a ranged
>   touch attack**. Any creature struck by the sphere takes 3d6 points of
>   damage from the force of its winds. *Spell Compendium, p. 62*

a) Does that mean the attack is part of the move action?

b) In case the opponent is [denied her Dex bonus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76501/if-you-make-a-ranged-touch-attack-with-an-ongoing-visible-spell-can-you-benefit), is she eliglible to sneak attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a) Does that mean the attack is part of the move action?

Yes. As a move action, you make a ranged touch attack, and the sphere hits that target.

That much is clear, but many other details in the spell are not. It’s not clear to me whether that movement has to be in a straight line (nothing *says* it has to, but a ranged attack kind of implies it), or what happens if the sphere touches anyone else en route (does it stop, blocked by that person? Pass through? Damage both? Just the first? Just the actual target?).

> b) In case the opponent is denied her Dex bonus, is she eliglible to sneak attack?

Yes; per *Complete Arcane*, sneak attack applies to “weapon-like” spells, that is, spells that involve some kind of attack roll. Touch attacks explicitly work, and this is a touch attack.

Comment: The quoted spell description says it *does* use a Ranged Touch Attack.

Comment: The spell description says you can make the sphere strike **a** creature or object, not any creature it touches.

Comment: @ObliviousSage It also says "Any creature **struck** by the sphere takes 3d6 points of damage," implying only one target gets affected per move action due to the consistent wording.

Comment: @MikeKellogg So it does, whoops. Very, very weird spell.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Unfortunately, I’m generally not really willing to put enough faith in the WotC editing team as to put so much weight on the choice of singular or plural.

Comment: That is two ranged touch sneak attacks with spells in a given round. A rogue-wizard's dream come true.  I have some more questions, but I think these deserve a new entry.